# How to fix CA1000 Do not declare static members on generic types

Tags: c#, .net-core

I'm using `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.FxCopAnalyzers` and the `CA1000` rule says the following.

> Do not declare static members on generic types.

**How to fix violations**

> To fix a violation of this rule, remove the static member or change it to an instance member.

**When to suppress warnings:**

> Do not suppress a warning from this rule. Providing generics in a syntax that is easy to understand and use reduces the time that is required to learn and increases the adoption rate of new libraries.

My code is the following. The `Success` method is the one which triggers the rule.

```
public class ResultResponse
{
    internal ResultResponse(bool isSuccess)
    {
        IsSuccess = isSuccess;
    }

    public bool IsSuccess { get; }

    public static ResultResponse Failed()
        => new ResultResponse(false);
}

public class ResultResponse<T> : ResultResponse
{
    internal ResultResponse(T value, bool isSuccess)
        : base(isSuccess)
    {
        Value = value;
    }

    public T Value { get; }

    public static ResultResponse<T> Success(T value)
        => new ResultResponse<T>(value, true);
}
```

I can make the constructor public and use it in the example above but I also have the case that I want to keep the constructor internal to ensure the type is used correctly.

Is moving the `Success` method to the non generic type the correct aproach?

```
public class ResultResponse
{
    internal ResultResponse(bool isSuccess)
    {
        IsSuccess = isSuccess;
    }

    public bool IsSuccess { get; }

    public static ResultResponse Failed()
        => new ResultResponse(false);

    public static ResultResponse<T> Success<T>(T value)
        => new ResultResponse<T>(value, true);
}

public class ResultResponse<T> : ResultResponse
{
    internal ResultResponse(T value, bool isSuccess)
        : base(isSuccess)
    {
        Value = value;
    }

    public T Value { get; }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is moving the `Success` method to the non generic type the correct aproach?

It's a decent approach. Note that now, you can call:

```
ResultResponse.Success(someat);
```

And the compiler will infer the generic type from `someat`. In your previous code, because you were calling the `static` method in the generic, you'd *always* have had to ("redundantly") specify the type parameter:

```
ResultResponse<int>.Success(someat);
```

Comment: What if you are not passing the object to the static method? e.g. Serializer.Deserialize<Type>(str)